# basename of file with a leading - (dash)

Tags: zsh, filenames, basename

I have a problem with basename in a zsh script. Imagine $directory containing a file name with a leading dash, in my case it's "-Fast-". Then the script executes

```
        folder=$(basename "$directory")
```

or if I try the other syntax of

```
        folder=`basename "$directory"`
```

it both leads to the same error:

basename: illegal option -- F
usage: basename string [suffix]
basename [-a] [-s suffix] string [...]

Other than not using files with a leading dash, which may be hard to explain to the common user, what do I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most commands, you can use a double dash `--` to tell "end of arguments".

```
folder=`basename -- "$directory"`
```

Answer (score 3):

How avoid `basename` altogether and just do a

```
folder=$directory:t
```

BTW, if you want the equivalent to `dirname` (i.e. the directory portion), it would be `$directory:h`.